# Query to add two images in table not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file, file-upload

I have an HTML form to upload some values including two images, I have two folders named uploads and receipt, I have given the following query to insert if the user fills the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    $image_name = time().".".$ext;
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $shame = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $shame);
    $receipt_name = time().".".$ext;
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploads/'.$image_name) && move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'receipt/'.$receipt_name) ){


        $sql = "INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, image, receipt) VALUES ('".$_POST['first_name']."','".$_POST['last_name']."' , '".$image_name."', '".$receipt_name."' )";
        $mysqli->query($sql);       
    }

    else {echo "Error";}

}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 17
> Error

Why is this query not adding the data to database, and not uploading the file?

Comment: Can you echo your query $sql and paste directly to phpmyadmin and see what result is coming.

Comment: @Sachin let me check

Comment: @Sachin there is no problem with the sql insert

Comment: Did you echo the query $sql? Please paste here so I'll check.

Comment: @Sachin how do i echo the query?

Answer (score -1):

Lets check if your code going in move_uploaded_file function or not and if yes then lets find out whats your query build.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    $image_name = time().".".$ext;
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $shame = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $shame);
    $receipt_name = time().".".$ext;
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploads/'.$image_name) && move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'receipt/'.$receipt_name) ){


        echo $sql = "INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, image, receipt) VALUES ('".$_POST['first_name']."','".$_POST['last_name']."' , '".$image_name."', '".$receipt_name."' )";
//paste this query into your phpmyadmin and check if its working or not.
die();
        $mysqli->query($sql);       
    }

    else {echo "Error";}

}
```

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat why don't you paste your $sql here.

Comment: @Sachin i checked the whole code, the problem is not with the query, it was with the php file upload, i am having error with it

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat - then do error reporting ON in this page and share the error why move_uploaded_function is not executing successfully.

Comment: @Sachin Undefined index: Photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: receipt in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 this is the error

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat The code you mentioned , I don't see you used photo and receipt in array. Then why it throwing this error. Are you sure this is the code is executing when you submit form.

Comment: the problem is here, $name = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
 list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
 $image_name = time().".".$ext;
 $tmp = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];

 $shame = $_FILES['receipt']['name'];
 list($txts, $exts) = explode(".", $shame);
 $receipt_name = time().".".$ext;
 $tmp = $_FILES['receipt']['tmp_name'];

 

 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploads/'.$image_name) && move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'receipt/'.$receipt_name))

Comment: can we start chat

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat - Sorry for the late reply, I was out a bit. So It seems like It cannot access the filename . Did you add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206907/discussion-between-sachin-and-zubair-nazer-oliyat).